# Angular transclusion and accessing controller scope

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

I have an angular application set up like this

```
<div ng-controller"FooCtrl">
  <bar></bar>
</div>
```

with the script

```
app.controller('FooCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.fn = function() { window.alert("Hello World"); }
}]);
app.directive('bar', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    templateUrl: "/bar.html",
  };
});
```

and the bar.html partial template being

```
<button ng-click="fn();">Exec</button>
```

but clicking that button does NOT work.

I tried adding

```
...
transclude:true
...
```

to the directive return, but this was no success.

How do I enable my access to the controller's function within a directive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to think of transclusion. Basically you had typo, `ng-controller` & `"FooCtrl"` should be separated by `=` sign

```
ng-controller="FooCtrl"
```

[**Plunkr Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/wDj1e8CcIZkSK49OAJ6s?p=preview)